# Vector2.right, left, and zero null reference error

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a way for a player to dash for as school project and Unity keeps telling me that Vector2.right, left, and zero aren't set to an instance of an object. My code displays no errors and I'm not sure what to do about this issue. I've included some pictures showing both my code and the errors I'm getting, which are on lines 40, 49, and 52.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewmxr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5fT8.png

Comment: Please include your source as text in your question (formatted as code using the `{}` button). Also include your errors as text (also formatted as code). As an interesting experiment, open your question on your phone and try to read your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.